# How can I create a trailing return type with primitives and Eigen?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, eigen, trailing-return-type

I want to write a template function in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) and I want to make a return type of the function to be flexible as possible. So sometimes the parameters which are taken by the function are primitives (`int`, `double`) but sometimes they can be containers or even `Eigen` objects!

So with primitives, I would simply write something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto normalise(T first, U second)
{
    return first * second;
}
```

But suppose if I would supply `Eigen::VectorXd`, that code will not work.  How can I overcome that barrier?

I was thinking to put an if statement but I will not be able to compare anything as parameters wouldn't be declared before that.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes correct, my case does not make sense :)

Comment: If you want to exclude the case of `Eigen::VectorXd`, simply use sfine. Or did I understand it wrong?

Comment: @JeJo I want to accept Eigen::VectorXd together with primitives or is it impossible?

Comment: Why shouldn't this work with `Eigen::VectorXd` (--> https://godbolt.org/z/bWVTgY)? This will return expression templates which may not be what you want, though. Also for `VectorXd * VectorXd` this will fail at runtime, unless the second vector has exactly one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple *[SFINE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error)* to sort out the types for which the template function should be instantiated.

```
// variable template for sorting out the allowed types
template<typename Type>
static constexpr bool is_allowed = std::is_same_v<Type, int> ||
                                   std::is_same_v<Type, double> || 
                                   std::is_same_v<Type, Eigen::VectorXd> 
                                   /* add other types which needed to be included */;

// type traits for sorting out the allowed types
template<typename T, typename U, typename ReType = void>
using enable_for_allowed_types = std::enable_if_t<
    is_allowed<T> && is_allowed<U>,
    ReType
>;

template<typename T, typename U>
auto normalise(T first, U second)
                -> enable_for_allowed_types<T, U, decltype(first*second)>
{
    return first * second;
}
```

Comment: Cheers mate, that is something new I have learned today, I will use that wherever I can when I need to resue my function and be flexible AF.

Comment: @Edmund Also have a look at std traits such as [std::is_fundamental](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_fundamental), [std::is_arithmetic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic), [std::is_floating_point](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_floating_point) and [std::is_integral](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral)  as per the requirements.